# Parsing and extracting all IDs from a document (using regex with capture)

Tags: parsing, regex, vb.net

I'm interested in parsing and extracting the IDs found in a document.  The IDs are found throughout the document in the this format:

> IDStart=1FG3392MQ9&IDEnd

The "1FG3392MQ9" is an example of such an ID (it will always appear between the IDStart and IDEnd tokens as in the above example). There will be text before and possibly after each occurrence and they could appear once on a given line or many times on a line.

Here's a utility function I have to parse and extract them:

```
Public Shared Function ParseALLDocumentIDs(text As String) As List(Of String)

   Dim allParsedIDs As New List(Of String)

   Dim IDregex As String = "IDStart=(.+?)&IDEnd"

   Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(text, IDregex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
   For Each m As Match In matches
       If m.Success Then
           Dim parsedID = m.GetFristCapture()
           If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parsedID) Then
               allParsedIDs.Add(parsedID)
           End If
       End If
   Next

   Return allParsedIDs           

 End Function
```

Upon each match, the following extension method is used (defined in another module) to get the first group capture of a match:

```
<Extension()>
    Public Function GetFristCapture(m As Match) As String

        ' Gets the first group capture "(...)" in a regex match.
        ' Returns empty string if not a match or there is no group capture found

        Dim capturedValue As String = ""

        If m IsNot Nothing AndAlso m.Success AndAlso m.Groups.Count > 1 Then
            ' Note: The first group is the entire match itself,
            ' so Group(1) is what we want, not Group(0)
            If m.Groups(1).Success Then

                capturedValue = m.Groups(1).Value.Trim

            End If
        End If

        Return capturedValue

    End Function
```

Questions:

1. How does the Regex look? Am I missing anything?  The idea was to capture all text between any occurrences of those two tokens, and do it non-greedily so that it doesn't capture across multiple tokens.
2. How does overall approach look with getting these IDs?  Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you're extracting (non-greedily) everything appearing between the `IDStart=` and `&IDEnd`. Since this is an ID, and generally the IDs are stored in alphanumeric character sets; you can easily replace the `.*?` with a `[a-z0-9]+` pattern. The `&` of the `&IDEnd` will take care of limiting your result between those two words alone.

However, if that is not your case, you should still replace the `.*?` with `.+?` so that you won't receive results/captures for a string like: `IDStart=&IDEnd`.

If the first rule applied to your case, then you can also remove the `.Trim` call from your `GetFristCapture` function.

**NOTE:** I assume that `GetFristCapture` is a typo. If not, you should rename it to `GetFirstCapture`.

The the `GetFristCapture` function itself, do not create a temporary variable. Just return from the `if` block itself:

```
Public Function GetFristCapture(m As Match) As String
    ' Gets the first group capture "(...)" in a regex match.
    ' Returns empty string if not a match or there is no group capture found
    If m IsNot Nothing AndAlso m.Success AndAlso m.Groups.Count > 1 Then
        ' Note: The first group is the entire match itself,
        ' so Group(1) is what we want, not Group(0)
        return m.Groups(1).Value
    End If
    Return ""
End Function
```

Note that I removed the nested `if` block as well. With your condition `m.Groups.Count > 1`, you're obviously getting `Group(0)` and `Group(1)`. Just return `Group(1)` from there.

Answer (score 0):

It's all a bit complicated in my opinion.  Perhaps you could do it like this, without the need for regex at all.

```
Public Shared Function GetDocumentIds(input As String) As List(Of String)

    Dim results = New List(Of String)()

    Dim sections = input.Split(New String() {"IDStart="}, StringSplitOptions.None)

    For Each section In sections
        Dim result = section.Split(New String() {"&IDEnd"}, StringSplitOptions.None)(0)

        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result) Then
            results.Add(result)
        End If
    Next

    Return results

End Function
```